# PHP corrupted when echo data from database to ajax

Tags: php, ajax, database

I have this problem and don't know what is causing it. 
When I load data to ajax my ajax script from www.something.tld/index.html they are ok. But when I load data from script.php which firstly retrieve data from db and then echo this data my ajax end with error. But the data output is the same! What's wrong?

example:
index.html output is "XXX"
script.php output is "XXX" but in my script I generate data with:

```
echo $data[0]->var;
```

Any idea why this happens? it happens when I retrieve data from db and then echo it out.

Internet Explorer said: Syntax error Line 281, character 163 in ttm/canvas.1.03.jgz
here is link for jgz http://www.freefilehosting.net/canvas103

I found out when I use anz function in php ajax will not parse output correctly!
this is parsed ok:

```
$from ='05/17/2012 10:15:00';
  $to ='05/17/2012 10:30:00';
  $day ='5/17/2012';
echo '{ "dtstart": "'.$from.'", "dtend": "'.$to.'", "day": "'.$day.'" },';
```

this is not parsed correctly:

```
$from= preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '',$data[0]->time_from);
$to  = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '',$data[0]->time_to);
$day = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '',$data[0]->day);
$from ='05/17/2012 10:15:00';
  $to ='05/17/2012 10:30:00';
  $day ='5/17/2012';
echo '{ "dtstart": "'.$from.'", "dtend": "'.$to.'", "day": "'.$day.'" },';
```

Comment: Hey, maybe try to post some code, and what errors are you getting by taking data with ajax.. plus, what library are you using to get data by ajax.

Comment: can u paste the ajax call code to let us determine what possibly might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json-encode) (like you're supposed to) then PHP takes care of all the encoding quirks for you. Such as escaping those non-printable characters and things past 0x7F.

```
echo json_encode(Array(
    "dtstart"=>$from,
    "dtend"=>$to,
    "day"=>$day
));
```

Depending on the encoding of your files, you may need to run the values through [`utf8_encode()`](http://php.net/utf8-encode) first, but that's something you have to test first and then try.